# Order should be as specified! error

Tags: python, lambda

```
def compose(f,g): 

  return lambda f: f + 1
  return lambda g: g
```

how can I specify the order of the return statements

These are the test cases;

```
add1 = lambda a: a+1
this   = lambda a: a

test.expect( compose(add1,this)(0) == 1 )
```

Comment: There is no error. It will return the first lambda which increments its input by 1. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: the requirement is return 2 functions, it fails tests where order is specified

Comment: How about `return (lambda f: f + 1, lambda g: g)` and access using their corresponding indexes?

Answer (score 2):

```
def compose(f1, g1):
    # do something
    return lambda f:f+1, lambda g:g
```

will return a tuple of two functions.

You can get the individual functions like this:

```
func1, func2 = compose(a,b)
```

Comment: same error in version without brackets

Comment: What error, exactly? The brackets don't matter here. The point being, you can return multiple variables with a single return statement.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two return statements in a function. Once the first one is called, the second will not be reached because the function has already returned. You could, however, use a [tuple](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm) to organize the output, which would look like this.

```
def compose(f,g):

    return (lambda f: f + 1, lambda g: g)
```

Be careful though, because this will return the actual lambdas as the below example shows:

```
In [7]: def func(f, g):                                                                                                                                                 
   ...:     return (lambda f: f + 1, lambda g: g)                                                                                                                       
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                 

In [8]: func(0, 0)                                                                                                                                                   
Out[8]: (<function __main__.<lambda>>, <function __main__.<lambda>>)
```

Notice the types shows by line out[8]. This means that what ever variables that the function returns to will be the actual functions, not a number. To return a number, don't use lambdas, just calculate the numbers normally.

It's also worth noting, that the parameters have no effect on this function.

Comment: tried this solution: "Traceback: in
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable"

Comment: its a codewar kata so I dont have access to the solution or any other error details

Comment: That is because you must specify which element to access first. The tuple is not a function but it contains the functions. Like arrays, use the [] operator to chose which function to use. This is explained at the link I provided as well.

Comment: @Conor I think that solving problems for Codewar is outside the scope of Stack Overflow. Perhaps study the terminology they use and what exactly that means in python and code in general for more insight.

Answer (score 0):

```
def compose(f,g): 

   return lambda f: f + 1,lambda g: g

print compose(f,g)[0]
print compose(f,g)[1]
```

Comment: Explaining why this works would be helpful to future readers.